# Двойные SQL-запросы (INSERT)

Tags: mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin

Привет. Постараюсь сжато пересказать свою задачу, которую я не могу решить по причине нехватки опыта.

Представьте, что у вас есть некая 
таблица1 с именами группы(id, group_name, element_name_id), которая ссылается на id элемента таблицы2(id, element_name), 
и обе они пустые Так строится эта примитивная связь. id - AI.

Предположим: мне нужно добавить за один либо несколько запросов поля Смартфон и Айфон, введенные юзером. Но дело в том, что команде нужно знать id из таблицы элементов в поле element_name_id, который бы еще сначала вставить, иначе произойдет не состыковка. Короче, именно над этим я и ломаю голову, и даже не знаю, что спрашивать в гугле. Очевидно, что это INSERT. Нужно, чтобы в таблице1 я увидел: имя: смартфон, element_id -> 0 Айфон.

Работаю в phpmyadmin и HeidiSQL.

Comment: Я делаю это примерно так:
При введении пользователем данных в таблицы, которые связаны с другими - создаю автоматически связанные таблицы и передаю из них последний id, который связываю основную. Но, так же как и вы, не знаю, правильно ли это

Answer (score 1):

Не надо мыслить штуками, мыслите массивами.
Первым запросом INSERT .. VALUES введите все данные в таблицу на стороне "один". А вторым - в таблицу на стороне "много" запросом INSERT .. SELECT.
При этом источником данных предложения SELECT является первая таблица, из которой Вы по только что введённым данным получаете требуемые для связи ID для вставки во вторую таблицу. Простейший пример:

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (`name`) VALUES ('Яблоки');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`table1_id`, `color`) 
    SELECT t1.ID, 'зелёные' 
    FROM `table1` t1 
    WHERE t1.`name` = 'Яблоки';
```

Comment: PS. Хоть в примере заносится по одному значению, ничего не мешает заносить их сразу пачками. Хотя как по мне, так лучше сперва их занести как есть во временную, а оттуда распарсить запросами по рабочим таблицам.